# Link Excel Chart Axis Scale to Values in Cells

Tags: vba, excel, charts, gantt-chart

I have this Gantt Chart and i'm looking at Planned Vs Actual dates.
the problem is that the chart wont sync the start/end date.

i'm trying to link the max/min values to the cell with VBA but it wont to it.

I tried to use this site:
https://peltiertech.com/link-excel-chart-axis-scale-to-values-in-cells/

but his code doesn't work for my chart.

here is a picture:
[image]

the dates MUST be the same, and change together if i change some values in the table on the right
any ideas?
thanks

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart 
Select Case Target.Address 

Case "$G$161" 
.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = Target.Value 

Case "$F$163" 
.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = Target.Value 

Case "$G$161" 
.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Target.Value 

Case "$F$163" 
.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Target.Value 

End Select 
End With 
End Sub
```

Comment: Please share us the code that you have tried. Thanks

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart
    Select Case Target.Address
      Case "$G$161"
        .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = Target.Value
      Case "$F$163"
        .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = Target.Value
      Case "$G$161"
        .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Target.Value
      Case "$F$163"
        .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Target.Value
    End Select
  End With
End Sub

Comment: just like from the site

Comment: It is possible In scatter chart  to set Axes(xlCategory).  And it is applied to Axes only.

Comment: Well, im not using a scatter chart. is there a macro for a bar chart?

Comment: You probably can't effectively use **two** `case` statements for a given value. Can you be more specific about what you mean by "doesn't work" and give more detail about the structure of your worksheet, in particular, are those cells G161 and F163 value literals, or are they containing a formula (which doesn't trigger the `Worksheet_Change` event.

Comment: yes, they are Vlookup formulas.
the chart is a simple Gantt chart with cycle time and dates.
but because i compare actual vs planned i show two Gantt charts in one chart.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have re-used is a simple demonstration program which allows the axes of a chart to be manipulated when one of 6 specific cells on the worksheet is changed. However, these changes are intended to be made by the user through the keyboard. Making a change in this way triggers the `Worksheet_Change` event and allows the changed cell to be identified. The code within the event routine modifies the chart's axes according to which specific worksheet cell has been changed.

Your issue, as David Ziemens noted in his comment, is that if a cell changes value because it is recalculated through a formula then this change does not trigger a `Worksheet_Change` event. (Of course, it is entirely possible that a manually entered change elsewhere on the worksheet will have triggered both a `Worksheet_Change` event and a recalculation causing a cell of interest to change its value via a formula. In this case, however, the `Target` argument will identify the cell that was manually changed rather than the one recalculated through a formula.)

Throw away the `Select ... Case` structure, that is really only useful in the context of the demonstration program you are trying to re-use. Instead, change the code so that it unconditionally updates all 4 of your chart properties directly from cells `G161` and `F163` (so use `ws.Range("G161").Value` and `ws.Range("F163").Value` instead of `Target.Value` for assigning the chart properties, where `ws` represents whichever worksheet these cells are located on - eg `ActiveSheet` or `Worksheets("Sheet1")` or whatever the worksheet is called). Wrap the assignment of the chart properties inside a `Workbook_SheetChange` sub rather than `Worksheet_Change` and your chart will update whenever the workbook recalculates.

This is not a very pure solution in that it does not detect whether cells `F163` and `G161` actually change when recalculation takes place. So it runs the risk that the 4 properties are being unnecessarily assigned with values that are unchanged. However, unless you have a very large workbook and you are pushing the limits of what your computer can handle, this won't matter from a practical point of view.

Comment: ok, thank you. i did what you said. changed a bit here and there.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
' for main axes
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Worksheets("Single 
Tool").Range("$G$161").Value
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Worksheets("Single 
Tool").Range("$F$163").Value

'for secondary axes
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MaximumScale = Worksheets("Single 
Tool").Range("$G$161").Value
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MinimumScale = Worksheets("Single 
Tool").Range("$F$163").Value


End With
End Sub
```

i found that this works best. thank you all